# PHP Error: Code always returning the same value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've made this code to login in to a site, but my code always returns `Onjuiste gegevens`*(incorrect data)*. I don't know why.

In my database I have made 1 account with username: sander and password: sander. When I enter this in the form I still get "Onjuiste gegevens". Could someone please help me to fix this?

```php
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "login");


if (isset($_POST['inloggen'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND '$password'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        echo "Juiste gegevens!";
    } else {
        echo "Onjuiste gegevens!";
    }

    echo "<br />";
}
?>
<form method="post" action="">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username"/><br />
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password"/><br />

    <input type="submit" name="inloggen" value="Inloggen"/>

</form>
```

Comment: Passwords should not be saved plain text, instead one calculates and stores a hash. Have a look at the [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. In this case you only search by username (not by password), and afterwards you check the entered password with the hash stored in the database [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a problem with your `query`, you've missed out `password`, it should be:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
```

Also, you should prevent `MySQL Injection`:

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
```

Read more about `mysqli_real_escape_string()` at http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp.

Also read up on `MySQLi Prepared Statements`: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php, it's a good way to prevent `MySQL Injection`.

**Tip:** Remember to store passwords hashed for security purposes. Do not store them as plain-text.

Comment: @SanderBakker You'll can prevent `MySQL Injection` using `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). This is a much better way of helping to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Your query's logic is wrong, you forget `password`:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password='$password'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not valid. You're forgetting the password column in your database.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
```

Besides having a wrong query, the query is open for sql injections.

Comment: Thanks. I got it working now!. Any guide for protection against sql injections?

Comment: Yes either use prepared statements or escape input with `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: Is it also possible to add a thrid thing to my query like "repeat password" if so. What would be my query?

Comment: Well it's possible but why would you want 2 password fields in your database ?

Comment: For safety. Saw it on some websites but got it coverd already

Comment: Also could you help me to make a logout php script from here. I really don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
```

which improves security by using **mysqli_real_escape_string()** for post variables.

**mysqli_real_escape_string()** -
Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement,

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.